# Java ShutDownHook not being fired on Windows

Tags: java, shutdown-hook

Ive got the following ShutdownHook to detect when the application is exited:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // Do what you want when the application is stopping
            sendMsg("", "goOfflineExit", "12");
        }
    }));
```

This works perfectly on Mac os but for some reason nothing gets fired on Windows.

Any ideas what im missing?

Comment: By what proof is it not getting triggered? Maybe it's just failing when it runs.

Comment: But more importantly, if you are using shutdown hooks for business logic, then that is your main problem. They are a last-resort mechanism with no helpful guarantees.

Comment: @Marko....No marko even in my case too the situation is same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two possible explanations:

- The `sendMsg(...)` call may be happening too late; e.g. after streams have been closed or flushed.
- The `sendMsg(...)` call may be throwing an exception.  Uncaught exceptions thrown in a shutdown hook typically don't get reported.

If you showed us the code of `sendMsg` we might be able to figure out a more definite answer.